# Migrating domain from AWS Route S3 to Linode

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dns-hosting, linode, dig

I want to migrate 1 domain from AWS Route S3 to Linode; I've changed the NS recods to point to

```
ns1.linode.com
ns2.linode.com
ns3.linode.com
ns4.linode.com
ns5.linode.com
```

but on the DNS checket it appears as NOT RESOLVED and when I dig this is the result:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.3 <<>> arteymiel.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14170
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;arteymiel.com.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
arteymiel.com.      820 IN  SOA ns-1690.awsdns-19.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 139.162.139.5#53(139.162.139.5)
;; WHEN: vie dic 25 07:19:23 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 126
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjHe6.png)

Comment: There's no such domain `arteydiez.com`.

Comment: sorry it is arteymiel.com

Comment: For that domain it appears you haven't changed the name servers at the registrar.

Comment: I added an image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvers can find records that point to your nameservers from two different places, the NS records you have just changed and the *glue* records that can be found at the parent name servers.

The glue records are the more important of the two because a resolver has no way of even finding your nameservers to ask what the NS records are without the glue records at the parent, and those glue records are still pointing at Amazon.

Since your registrar is also Amazon, to change the glue records you can go to Route53 and click on the **Registered domains** section (underneath **Hosted Zones**), then click on your domain and click on **Add or edit name servers** on the right hand side.

As a side note, you may also run into troubles with a TTL of 1 on those NS records. I wouldn't leave it like that indefinitely. It's unusual to see NS records with a TTL shorter than 86400.